# Zipping two lists won't make a tuple?

Tags: list, python-2.7, tuples

```
weekinfo=[]
for k in sats:
    weekinfo.append(get_weekly(k, satdict))
yearend=get_weekly('end_year', satdict)
weektuples=zip(sats, weekinfo)
```

- Sats is a list with 52 items. [ date, date, date, etc]
- Weekinfo is a nested list (thus 52 lists in a list) with in each nested list with in each list 100 tuples.

I am trying to make a tuples (weektuples) in the last line via zip(sats, weekinfo). However, the output are not tuples but a lists.

Is there a solution to create tuples with Sats and Weekinfo?

Comment: "trying to make a tuples" - `zip` will still make a list here, is that okay?

Comment: I need tuples as result of weektuples = zip(sats, weekinfo)

Comment: What do you mean by "I need week tuples"? Can you give an example of what the structure of `weektuples` should look like? `zip` will return a list of 2-tuples, pairing an item from `sats` with an item from `weekinfo` (without changing the types of those items).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 x=52
 sats = np.linspace(1,x,x)
 print sats
 weekinfo=[]
 satdict= ['m', 't', 'w', 'u', 'f', 'sa', 'su']
 for k in range(x):
     weekinfo.append((sats[int(k)], satdict[int(k)%7]))
 print weekinfo
```

Not sure that's the exact answer you're looking for, but something along those lines might work

Comment: Trying to understand you, but not there yet :-) I need weektuples=zip(sats, weekinfo) to deliver tuples.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to do, but I tried checking out tuple references to see if that has something that can help you: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm.  Can you clarify what you're trying to do without referring to code?